# return array or list of objects in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm new to Solidity and trying to make some modification in the code I found on Internet. Given below is the VANET contract:

```
contract VANET {
    string name;
    string owner;
    string number;
    string license;
    event Vehicle(
        string name,
        string owner,
        string number,
        string license
    );
    function setVehicle(string _name, string _owner, string _number, string _license) public{
        name=_name;
        owner=_owner;
        number=_number;
        license=_license;
        Vehicle(_name, _owner, _number, _license);
    }
    function getVehicle() public constant returns (string, string, string, string){
        return (name, owner, number, license);
    }
```

When I try to call getVehicle() using following code:

```
 VANET.methods.getVehicle().call().then(r=>{
        console.log(r);  //outputs only the last vehicle added
      })
```

it shows only last added vehicle. What I want is the list of all the vehicles that are added to the blockchain using setVehicle() function. How can I do That?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you invoke `setVehicle()`, it **rewrites** values of the storage properties.

So the most straightforward way to group all those values in a `struct` (an object-like type) and then place those structs in an array, so that you can keep all input values. Then you can simply retrieve the whole array:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract VANET {
    struct Vehicle {
        string name;
        string owner;
        string number;
        string license;
    }
    Vehicle[] private vehicles;

    event VehicleAdded(
        string name,
        string owner,
        string number,
        string license
    );

    function addVehicle(string memory _name, string memory _owner, string memory _number, string memory _license) public {
        vehicles.push(
            Vehicle(_name, _owner, _number, _license)
        );
        emit VehicleAdded(_name, _owner, _number, _license);
    }

    function getVehicles() public view returns (Vehicle[] memory) {
        return vehicles;
    }
}
```

*It seems that your snippet is using a deprecated version of Solidity (I'm guessing 0.4), and I wrote the example using the latest version 0.8. There are some slight syntax changes between those versions, so just keep that in mind.*

Comment: works great, how would I remove a specific item from the array?

Comment: @MaygaFatmawati You'll need to know the index of the item. Then there are several ways: 1) `delete vehicles[index]` empties its values but leaves a gap in the array... 2) Copy values of the last item to the "deleted" index, and then use `vehicles.pop()` to remove the last item. This doesn't leave a gap but reorders the array... 3) Loop from `index+1` to `length-1` and copy values of each of these items to the one back. It doesn't leave a gap, doesn't reorder the array, but the gas costs grow linearly with the amount of items that you're moving.

Answer (score 0):

Your solidity codes only accepts one input of Vehicle. To keep a list of all vehicle added, you can add them into an array.

Here's an (albeit crude) example.

```
contract VANET {
Vehicle[] vehicles;

struct Vehicle{
    string name;
    string owner; 
    string number; 
    string license;
}

event VehicleEvent(
    string name,
    string owner,
    string number,
    string license
);

function setVehicle(string memory _name, string memory _owner, string memory _number, string memory _license) public{
    vehicles.push(Vehicle(_name, _owner, _number, _license));
    emit VehicleEvent(_name, _owner, _number, _license);
}

function getVehicle(uint256 id) public view returns (string memory name, string memory owner, string memory number, string memory license) {
    return (vehicles[id].name, vehicles[id].owner, vehicles[id].number, vehicles[id].license);
}}
```